# Artifacts and flickering in renderd animation but not in rendered view

Tags: rendering, artifacts, denoise, noise-reduction, .exr

I rendered an animation and there are weird artifacts that almost look like refractions:

[image]

There is also weird flickering in the hair, but I assume thats caused by the low sample rate and the low light, but i dont know where the sharp artifacts (at her nose) are coming from. Also the black shadows on the wall behind her head are also weird and not there in rendered view, they also appear at the very beginning of the render so I dont think the denoiser is causing them. The artifacts show up every few frames, heres another example with the artifacts at the armpit.

[image]

Any suggestions on what to do, i tried to update the graphics driver but that didnt do anything.

Also could I get less noise by changeing the exposure in the render tab and then darkening everything in post or will that not impact noise.
Or do I maybe need to switch to exr instead of pngs, any advice is welcome.

Comment: You've got a lot of tattoos and perhaps a nose bridge, so perhaps you can edit your screencap and draw circles around what you consider 'weird artifacts'?  It looks like the shaders on her skin (nose, lower lip) are a bit too reflective (specular high, roughness low)?

Comment: I added some circles, thanks for notifying me should've done that in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what was causing the artifacting, its motion blur in combination with auto smoothing on meshes with heavy animation, in this case her body. I fixed it just by turning it to smooth shading which doesnt really look different anyways.
Here are side by side examples:

[image]
[image]

The shadows over her head were caused by the red lamps being slightly inside the ceiling.